# Nuodb - is there encryption option for data storage?

Tags: nuodb

Is encryption supported within nuodb?
I was trying to get that from [manaual](http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Default.htm#Reference-Information.htm).

I need to fulfill some security requirements -> encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data at rest, NuoDB supports use of encrypted file systems for database storage.  NuoDB does not yet support column-level encryption.  For data in motion, NuoDB uses SRP (RFC-2945) for mutual authentication between application clients and NuoDB nodes, and a configurable cypher for encryption of all IPC sessions.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Could you add a link to this?